# General Addition Rule for $3$ events

Tags: probability

For $3$ events $A$, $B$, and $C$...

$P(A$ and $B$ and $C) = 0.1$

$P(A$ and $B) = 0.3$

$P(A$ and $C) = 0.2$

$P(B$ and $C) = 0.4$

$P(A) = P(B) = P(C)$

What is $P(A)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like homework.

Anyway, note that P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A and C)-P(A and B)-P(B and C)+P(A, B, and C)=1. Think about a Venn diagram where you try to count everything. You can try using all the circles, but the areas within two of the circles are counted twice, so you subtract them.

But the area in the very center has been counted 3 times, and then subtracted 3 times. So it's not even counted right now! That forces us to add the probability of all three events occurring.

Either way, this equation gives 3P(A)-0.9+0.1=1, so $P(A)=\frac{1.8}{3}=\boxed{0.6}$.

Comment: Sorry! Just a test question I wanted cleared up. I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: What makes you think that $P(A\cup B\cup C)=1$?  I do not see that hypothesis or any equivalent hypothesis anywhere in the original post.

Comment: Dang, I completely missed that! Nice catch. But given the way the problem is stated, I would assume that's so. Also, @bhargav.y: no problem ;) In addition, you should read the above comment.